# how to get excel particular cell value for in while loop

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I am new with python and pandas, I have a text file (data.txt) in which "content" is like.  "123 456 789 101123 456 789 101 112 113 110  112 123 456 789 101 112 113 110 113 123 456 789 101 112 113 110 110 ............. " etc. and having an excel file (combination.xlsx) which is carrying some combination. (In excel sheet cell A1 = 123 456, A2 = 456 789, A3 = 789 101123, .................), my Problem is how to use/get each cell value from (combination.xlsx) to use for count of frequency of occurrence which may available in data.txt and print in another text file (final.txt). want to make a while loop which will start with picking the first cell value )A1) and start a loop and if it is = to or more then 1 then it will print in final.txt otherwise it should pick second cell value(A2).. till cell value/data is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't need an explicit while loop here. You can get each cell value using [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)
which returns a `dataframe` with all cells. To count the frequency of occurrence, for each row of the dataframe you can use `len` over the `re.findall` with the following regular expression: `\b({x})\b`. This regex assures that the number sequence (`x` on this particular f-string) will match only between [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). To print to another file, you can use `df["Qnt"].`[to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

data_txt = "123 456 789 101123 456 789 101 112 113 110 112 123 456 789 101 112 113 110 113 123 456 789 101 112 113 110 110"

# read XLSX cells
df = pd.read_excel("combination.xlsx", header=None, names=["Comb"])

# count occurrences
find_qnt = lambda x: len(re.findall(rf"\b({x})\b", data_txt))

# apply to each row
df["Qnt"] = df["Comb"].apply(find_qnt)
print(df)

# print into another text file
df["Qnt"].to_csv("final.txt", index=False)
```

Output from *df*

```py
         Comb  Qnt
0     123 456    3
1     456 789    4
2  789 101123    1
```